# PrestaShop Product Combinations

Tags: php, prestashop

Is there a way to create **Product "Combinations"** with **Categories** instead of attributes? Either from the backend or programmatically?

I have a wine database and the same bottle can be sold by two different "categories" but price may differ.

A wine seller will be stored as a "Category" to cater for my website's needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way for you is to keep combinations based on attributes, and use the [layered block](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Making+The+Native+Modules+Work#MakingTheNativeModulesWork-Layerednavigationblock) instead of categories block. You can also create a custom categories block with your wine seller attribute.

I discouraged you to modify the combinations logic, it's too complex and will not be update proof.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you can customize the view and pricing by customer groups. To give you the best advice I would need to know what exactly you are trying to accomplish on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

[Category Product Combinations](http://masterpro.ws/category-product-combinations-prestashop-module). Free prestashop module. Maybe this will help. ))

Comment: Links to third party software or plug-ins are frowned upon by the Stack Overflow community. Stack Overflow is geared more towards offering assistance writing source code.